# Juniper EX4200 how to select s-vlan from c-vlan on dot1q-tunneling access port?

Tags: vlan, juniper, juniper-junos, qinq

How do I tell Juniper EX4200 to push specific S-VLAN based on C-VLAN on q-in-q (dot1q-tunneling)  port?

For instance I want to instruct EX4200 to perform Q-in-Q using these rules:

```
1) If a single-tag frame is received on ge-0/0/0 with C-VLAN=41, push S-VLAN=4.
2) If a single-tag frame is received on ge-0/0/0 with C-VLAN=42, push S-VLAN=4.
3) If a single-tag frame is received on ge-0/0/0 with C-VLAN=51, push S-VLAN=5.
4) If a single-tag frame is received on ge-0/0/0 with C-VLAN=52, push S-VLAN=5.
```

Conversely, whenever a double-tag frame is to be sent on ge-0/0/0, the outter S-VLAN ought to be removed (popped).

Can this be done with Juniper EX4200? If so, please point out the specific configuration commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you are after:

```
    set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching port-mode access
    set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members SVID4
    set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members SVID5
    set vlans SVID4 vlan-id 4
    set vlans SVID4 dot1q-tunneling customer-vlans 41-42
    set vlans SVID4 dot1q-tunneling layer2-protocol-tunneling all
    set vlans SVID5 vlan-id 5
    set vlans SVID5 dot1q-tunneling customer-vlans 51-52
    set vlans SVID5 dot1q-tunneling layer2-protocol-tunneling all
```

Cheers,

H