# Cisco QinQ - More than one provider vlan (s-vlan) on dot1q-tunnel port

Tags: cisco, vlan, tunnel, qinq, dot1q

When we configure a qinq tunneling, the port, which performs the encapsulation, has the next command-lines:

```
interface g0/10
  switchport
  switchport mode dot1q-tunnel
  switchport access vlan xxx <-- s-vlan
exit
```

So, on my job environment, if i want encapsulate another c-vlan (customer vlan) using a diferent s-vlan, I have to use another port and this option isn't scalable (one port for each s-vlan).

Do you know about a method to encapsulate many c-vlans using different s-vlans on the same port? I tried with vlan-mapping or vlan translation, but this method doesn't perform encapsulation, only replaces the original tag with the s-vlan tag.

Help me!

Comment: What equipment are you using?

Comment: I'm using Cisco 3560G and Huawei s5700

Comment: Juniper EX4200 can do it: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30509/juniper-ex4200-how-to-select-s-vlan-from-c-vlan-on-dot1q-tunneling-access-port

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need "Selective Q-in-Q" documented [here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/12-2/15-02SG/configuration/guide/config/tunnel.html)

E.g.

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/23
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport vlan mapping 21 dot1q-tunnel 211
 switchport vlan mapping 31 dot1q-tunnel 311
```

Comment: Hello! Thank's for your answer, it opens my mind. Currently I'm using huawei devices, they have the "vlan stacking" solution, it works as a selective QinQ.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure dot1q-tunnel, all customer traffic is encapsulated with s-vlan.

Your customer can encapsulate his own traffic, with a c-vlan. In that case, you receive in your switch 802.1q traffic, and you can carry multiple customer vlans with one s-vlan in your network.

But is no possible to use different s-vlans in the same port.

This scenario can be possible using different tecnologies, like MPLS or VXLAN.

Comment: Juniper EX4200 can do it: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30509/juniper-ex4200-how-to-select-s-vlan-from-c-vlan-on-dot1q-tunneling-access-port

Comment: I don't have Juniper devices.

Answer (score 0):

The goal with q-in-q is to take all the customer c-vlans and switch them in a single s-vlan.

You configure q-in-q on the inbound interface from the customer, thus taking all his c-vlans and switching it through the internal network on s-vlan.

It is not a one to one, there is multiple c-vlans all inside a s-vlan.

Each client is handles in a single s-vlan.